# Distribution function of r.v. $\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have the following exercise:

[image]

I don't know if I have done the exercise correctly. Please tell me if my reasoning is correct:

1) Define $Y = \min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$;

2) Obtain the distribution function $F_Y(y)$ as follows (having in mind that $X_i$ are independent):
\begin{align}
 F_Y(y) &= \mathrm P(Y\leq y) = \mathrm P(\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\leq y) \\ 
&= 1 - \mathrm P(\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)>y) \\
&= 1 - \mathrm P(X_1>y) \times \cdots \times \mathrm P(X_n>y) \\
&= 1 - ( 1 - \mathrm P(X_1 \leq y)) \times \cdots \times ( 1 - \mathrm P(X_n \leq y))  \\
&= 1 - ( 1 - F_1(y)) \times \cdots \times ( 1 - F_n(y)) \\
&=  1 - \prod_{i=1}^n (1 - F_i(y))
\end{align}

3) The density function is given by:

$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy} F_Y(y) = ( 1 - f_1(y)) \times \cdots \times ( 1 - f_n(y))
$$
I believe some of the things I wrote are wrong! Can someone please correct me and tell the steps (or resolution) that I should follow! Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does $1-\prod_{i=1}^n (1 - F_i(y))$ equal $\prod_{i=1}^n F_i(y)$? And you have to use the product rule for differentiating.

Comment: It does not, my bad!

Comment: But what about the rest, that is a detail! If someone could please help me I would appreciate it!

Comment: Well you were supposed to calculate the distribution function, not the PDF of $Y$. The answer is $1-\prod_{i=1}^n(1-F_i(y))$ and further simplification is only possible if the actual expression of $F_i(y)$ is given. Your solution is correct.

Comment: The derivative of the product is not the product of derivatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct about the distribution function:

$$F_Y(y)=P(Y<y)=1-\prod_i \left(1-F_i(y)\right)$$

The derivative of this is more complicated. You get:

$$\begin{align}f_Y(y)&=-\frac{d}{dy}\prod_i \left(1-F_i(y)\right)\\
&=\sum_{j} \left[f_j(y)\prod_{i\neq j}\left(1-F_i(y)\right)\right]
\end{align}$$

Each term in the sum is the probability density for $X_j$ at $y$ times the probability that each of the other variables are greater than $y.$